# It might be a way to let your sorrow go away

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you tell me, please, these sentences sounds good or awkward? If they are awkward, please write your version.

I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge to make a conclusion about them. Maybe, a phrase "might be a way to let..." isn't so good.

> Listening to some good music **might be a way to let your sorrow go away**.
>
> Listening to some good music **might let your sorrow go away**.

Comment: Want a quick and useful answer? Generally, with emotions: Let your sorrow go. [don't keep hold of it] **versus** make your sorrow go away. That's your case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They sound a bit awkward. I think the problem is the combination of "let", "go" and "away"; trying to use all three is awkward/difficult. Let go of one of the three.

Some possible alternatives:

- might be a way to **let go** of your sorrow
- might be a way to **let** your sorrow **fly away**
- might be a way to let your sorrow melt away
- might be a way to let your sorrow wash away
- might be a way **for** your sorrow **to go away**
- might be a way **to make** your sorrow **go away**
- might **melt** your sorrow **away**
- might wash your sorrow away

(The nuances are different, but the overall meaning is the same.)